# Cplex giving infeasible in objective column of log output

Tags: machine-learning, ibm-watson, linear-programming, cplex

I'm getting an infeasible row in objective column of logs, and beacuse of that model keeps running for longs hours.
for given number of constriants model keeps runing for hours and it runs out of memory(even 128GB) , this seems very problematic to assign such heavy resources. I'm attaching logoutput. please help me to how to figure this issue

```
Model: docplex_model2
- number of variables: 457809
   - binary=0, integer=456048, continuous=0, semi-continuous=1761
 - number of constraints: 37076
   - linear=37076
 - parameters:
     parameters.emphasis.mip = 1
     parameters.mip.tolerances.mipgap = 0.35000000000000
 - objective: maximize
 - problem type is: MILP
```

here is log output----

```
CPXPARAM_Emphasis_MIP                            1
CPXPARAM_MIP_Tolerances_MIPGap                   0.34999999999999998
Tried aggregator 3 times.
MIP Presolve eliminated 4748 rows and 61614 columns.
MIP Presolve modified 16 coefficients.
Aggregator did 19860 substitutions.
Reduced MIP has 15990 rows, 377635 columns, and 769615 nonzeros.
Reduced MIP has 3955 binaries, 372041 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators.
Presolve time = 2.21 sec. (2205.73 ticks)
Tried aggregator 1 time.
Detecting symmetries...
Reduced MIP has 15990 rows, 377635 columns, and 769615 nonzeros.
Reduced MIP has 3955 binaries, 372041 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators.
Presolve time = 1.86 sec. (1558.18 ticks)
Probing fixed 1 vars, tightened 291 bounds.
Probing time = 0.16 sec. (46.27 ticks)
Clique table members: 3626.
MIP emphasis: integer feasibility.
MIP search method: dynamic search.
Parallel mode: deterministic, using up to 4 threads.
Root relaxation solution time = 1.17 sec. (760.41 ticks)

        Nodes                                         Cuts/
   Node  Left     Objective  IInf  Best Integer    Best Bound    ItCnt     Gap

      0     0  5447054.2576   568                5447054.2576     7411         
      0     0  5446256.0396  2550                  Cuts: 3105    11523         
      0     0  5445582.9819  3313                  Cuts: 2609    15362         
      0     0  5443111.8900  3879                  Cuts: 1793    19392         
      0     1  5443111.8900  3879                5443111.8900    19392         
Elapsed time = 28.84 sec. (18204.70 ticks, tree = 0.02 MB, solutions = 0)
      7     8  5424995.5661  3422                5427140.2491    19602         
     12    13  5424025.4253  2980                5427140.2491    19901         
     19    20  5424008.3599  2834                5427140.2491    20019         
     24    23  5423705.3128  3481                5427119.7653    22030         
     26    24  5424539.9397  4284                5427057.2493    22919         
     28    26  5423701.9049  3508                5427057.2493    24217         
     31    31  5423519.5986  3292                5427024.1000    32459         
     34    31  5424673.8781  3987                5426984.4114    34984         
     36    34  5424539.1738  4209                5426984.4114    37899         
     48    44  5424035.7444  3884                5426984.4114    40985         
Elapsed time = 32.69 sec. (22078.80 ticks, tree = 5.41 MB, solutions = 0)
    127    74  5422280.0110  3032                5426984.4114    42820         
    219   164  5422903.9976  3221                5426984.4114    44186         
    305   255  5422151.6347  2984                5426984.4114    46975         
    388   316  5409466.1277  2461                5426984.4114    47488         
    457   391  5419580.4261  2238                5426984.4114    50940         
    506   448  5419173.6547  2131                5426984.4114    57287         
    553   481  5401742.1028  1718                5426984.4114    63918         
    591   529  5389251.7601  1272                5426984.4114    72056         
    632   574    **infeasible**                      5426984.4114    79106         
    675   596  5398682.6980  1566                5426984.4114    81099         
Elapsed time = 43.66 sec. (31720.81 ticks, tree = 181.23 MB, solutions = 0)
    705   609  5404307.7518  1513                5426984.4114    85133         
    754   657  5422924.3660  3173                5426984.4114    97279         
    825   726  5420872.5251  2739                5426984.4114   101585         
    898   763  5384923.7790  1488                5426984.4114   103060         
    966   843  5376292.5417   937                5426984.4114   107764         
   1031   898  5394081.5952  1003                5426984.4114   109361         
   1101   976  5372102.4281  1103                5426984.4114   112509         
   1173  1036  5393219.2485   869                5426984.4114   116229         
   1252  1106  5398144.9886  1754                5426984.4114   117850         
   1330  1148  5371456.5486   868                5426984.4114   121077         
Elapsed time = 54.19 sec. (41408.05 ticks, tree = 534.37 MB, solutions = 0)
   1400  1262  5396613.5760  1430                5426984.4114   126293         
   1482  1300  5392103.1569   819                5426984.4114   125806         
   1563  1428  5396352.6299  1234                5426984.4114   133285         
   1638  1459  5391806.7612   764                5426984.4114   134133         
   1701  1540  5371435.0973   678                5426984.4114   135347         
   1755  1603  5391965.9348   717                5426984.4114   141811         
   1806  1656  5421590.6214  3079                5426984.4114   145378         
   1873  1687  5386074.1901   649                5426984.4114   148265         
   1916  1780  5406119.1903  2245                5426984.4114   158126         
   1952  1802  5400035.4985  1963                5426984.4114   158659         
Elapsed time = 65.70 sec. (51106.01 ticks, tree = 956.74 MB, solutions = 0)
   1993  1837  5399984.5162  1714                5426984.4114   164792         
   2046  1868  5399199.1117  1709                5426984.4114   176903         
   2116  1900  5409091.4055  2920                5426984.4114   180187         
   2194  1956  5409096.1850  2748                5426984.4114   185734         
   2263  2045  5395631.1560  1229                5426984.4114   191503         
   2299  2083  5417884.0649  2180                5426984.4114   195258         
   2307  2106  5394566.8771  1769                5426984.4114   199129         
   2326  2131  5409642.8769  2386                5426984.4114   209111         
   2337  2129  5393094.1052  1774                5426984.4114   214143         
   2344  2160  5380420.7567  2071                5426984.4114   232449         
Elapsed time = 76.93 sec. (61429.58 ticks, tree = 1067.83 MB, solutions = 0)
   2395  2173  5412998.2623  3089                5426984.4114   244438         
   2445  2184  5311151.8238  1640                5426984.4114   255958         
   2499  2213  5401804.4871  2029                5426984.4114   258719         
   2531  2282  5393804.1209  1771                5426984.4114   267432         
   2579  2272  5415355.4047  3780                5426984.4114   267184         
   2615  2319  5310045.7515  1240                5426984.4114   269611         
   2663  2377  5408859.8378  2442                5426984.4114   279749         
   2726  2401  5379550.1445  1486                5426984.4114   282757         
   2791  2439  5309774.2007  1177                5426984.4114   290254         
   2834  2510  5413748.0466  3160                5426984.4114   295756         
Elapsed time = 89.00 sec. (71126.64 ticks, tree = 1263.45 MB, solutions = 0)
   2853  2525  5408741.2417  2684                5426984.4114   296581         
   2880  2525  5415209.9026  4120                5426984.4114   303367         
   2916  2566  5418536.5596  3645                5426984.4114   315754         
   2964  2626  5408703.1497  2705                5426984.4114   323603         
   3021  2691  5407778.6853  2649                5426984.4114   329944         
   3086  2716  5399275.4604  2268                5426984.4114   333471         
   3160  2799  5399364.7532  2316                5426984.4114   337939         
   3236  2832  5398929.9160  1705                5426984.4114   340882         
   3292  2928  5398898.9016  1704                5426984.4114   343929         
   3350  2948  5398898.9008  1683                5426984.4114   344110         
Elapsed time = 99.95 sec. (80755.29 ticks, tree = 1414.32 MB, solutions = 0)
   3410  2969  5397943.8252  1840                5426984.4114   351908         
   3462  3018  5395313.6357   986                5426984.4114   353878         
   3513  3110  5395311.0280   993                5426984.4114   357262         
   3577  3127  5395288.3990   904                5426984.4114   358271         
   3645  3168  5397199.3357  1114                5426984.4114   370737         
   3718  3215  5395066.1468   754                5426984.4114   373522         
   3788  3339  5395066.1391   700                5426984.4114   381975         
   3857  3388  5395944.8892   819                5426984.4114   383179         
   3920  3458  5395066.1391   629                5426984.4114   386279         
   3985  3437  5396858.2083   850                5426984.4114   385567         
Elapsed time = 111.67 sec. (90345.62 ticks, tree = 1588.45 MB, solutions = 0)
   4031  3491  5407565.7631  2780                5426984.4114   400026         
   4098  3640  5405298.0780  2396                5426984.4114   402831         
   4177  3695  5395052.5234   608                5426984.4114   406870         
   4250  3737  5395869.1675   682                5426984.4114   409458         
   4316  3812  5396858.2017   739                5426984.4114   413233         
   4393  3832  5396858.1944   733                5426984.4114   413317         
   4471  3900  5394988.6288   546                5426984.4114   413564         
   4555  4072  5395869.0990   608                5426984.4114   419039         
   4644  4021  5396858.1910   623                5426984.4114   419080         
   4733  4115  5395869.0973   590                5426984.4114   419752         
Elapsed time = 122.15 sec. (99976.83 ticks, tree = 1856.46 MB, solutions = 0)
   4819  4250  5394988.6220   491                5426984.4114   421914         
   4898  4366    **infeasible**                      5426984.4114   425370         
   4975  4468  5379274.3718   563                5426984.4114   426559         
   5058  4402  5396199.1795   588                5426984.4114   426041         
   5138  4600  5394342.0730   473                5426984.4114   429670         
   5217  4712  5396952.6974   810                5426984.4114   431089         
   5301  4749  5395586.7800   581                5426984.4114   431476         
   5383  4908  5396951.9009   738                5426984.4114   432228         
   5471  4789  5395586.7800   569                5426984.4114   431655         
   5705  5202  5389705.4806   535                5426984.4114   438101         
Elapsed time = 138.72 sec. (112480.76 ticks, tree = 2314.33 MB, solutions = 0)
Nodefile size = 249.91 MB (135.33 MB after compression)
   5879  5330  5395614.4696   496                5426984.4114   450886         
   6168  5528  5389681.1285   545                5426984.4114   474496         
   6484  5744  5389680.1611   498                5426984.4114   482597         
   6810  6058  5395611.1982   431                5426984.4114   502814         
   7033  6364  5388473.8481   490                5426984.4114   511099         
   7248  6504  5387478.5235   518                5426984.4114   527293         
   7478  6674  5387476.9499   490                5426984.4114   545602         
   7761  6958    infeasible                      5426984.4114   566811         
   8105  7342  5392996.6596  1078                5426984.4114   571908         
   8434  7579  5387466.8418   444                5426984.4114   574887         
Elapsed time = 192.15 sec. (150730.09 ticks, tree = 3461.46 MB, solutions = 0)
Nodefile size = 1384.18 MB (691.75 MB after compression)
   8709  7810  5397037.0153   838                5426984.4114   578870         
   9007  8112  5384414.0235  2186                5426984.4114   597517         
   9269  8293  5396621.2916   673                5426984.4114   596439         
   9509  8665  5394951.1841   365                5426984.4114   614950         
   9781  8916  5396630.9062  1311                5426984.4114   632021         
  10039  9090  5387434.8861   342                5426984.4114   638327         
  10277  9353  5386224.1164   328                5426984.4114   655878         
  10528  9467  5382940.5147  1184                5426984.4114   681490         
  10865  9891  5379821.1913   683                5426984.4114   696064         
  11275 10109  5386092.4028   307                5426984.4114   704392         
Elapsed time = 245.52 sec. (189003.15 ticks, tree = 4796.42 MB, solutions = 0)
Nodefile size = 2692.95 MB (1435.87 MB after compression)
  11597 10675  5377146.8013   627                5426984.4114   710049         
  11877 10706  5395739.9394  1911                5426984.4114   724018         
  12115 11083  5380946.8455   775                5426984.4114   735232         
  12416 11357  5390818.3099   896                5426984.4114   741661         
  12804 11901  5326007.6723   638                5426984.4114   776244         
  13121 12085  5378349.6560   620                5426984.4114   779793         
  13458 12363  5389599.2004   643                5426984.4114   788537         
  13824 12733  5325990.7395   548                5426984.4114   792704         
  14090 13096  5325963.0516   600                5426984.4114   805870         
  14354 13319  5397488.8033  1782                5426984.4114   818543         
Elapsed time = 302.45 sec. (227261.05 ticks, tree = 6271.27 MB, solutions = 0)
Nodefile size = 4188.32 MB (2302.65 MB after compression)
  14627 13512  5386890.7225   556                5426984.4114   821318         
  14895 13829  5386888.5939   524                5426984.4114   831183         
  15187 13963  5377020.3945   504                5426984.4114   834645         
  15455 14294  5377020.3898   505                5426984.4114   844715         
  15680 14635  5377020.4007   520                5426984.4114   852027         
  15976 14783  5381527.6047   733                5426984.4114   856152         
  16177 14937  5381511.9443   520                5426984.4114   861753         
  16451 15339  5376578.6410   473                5426984.4114   876699         
  16689 15404  5325878.3808   610                5426984.4114   879652         
  16935 15755  5325878.3164   613                5426984.4114   891454         
Elapsed time = 356.26 sec. (265571.16 ticks, tree = 7501.52 MB, solutions = 0)
Nodefile size = 5404.22 MB (3002.08 MB after compression)
  17160 16158  5401085.5148   771                5426984.4114   910569         
  17388 16285  5380972.9071   472                5426984.4114   912559         
  17663 16416  5376553.4444   432                5426984.4114   915484         
  17996 16789  5391612.5021  1154                5426984.4114   945195         
  18370 17016  5399149.8996   661                5426984.4114   946617         
  18699 17178  5376545.5419   431                5426984.4114   950159         
  19014 17641  5379024.1276   486                5426984.4114   954633         
  19340 17899  5383193.5734   645                5426984.4114   960081         
  19581 18232  5376404.4175   428                5426984.4114   961628         
  19853 18478    **infeasible**                      5426984.4114   981564         
Elapsed time = 413.45 sec. (303842.46 ticks, tree = 8828.29 MB, solutions = 0)
Nodefile size = 6720.90 MB (3762.30 MB after compression)
  20165 18909  5385867.9420  1066                5426984.4114   994135         
  20457 19070  5379016.2952   432                5426984.4114   994483         
  20728 19337  5360733.6497   607                5426984.4114  1001533         
  21024 19760  5360732.4758   599                5426984.4114  1011198         
  21356 19923  5385581.0389   620                5426984.4114  1014584         
  21702 20302  5360727.4646   589                5426984.4114  1016715         
  22022 20494  5384699.5095   546                5426984.4114  1018323         
  22309 20749  5372959.8072   431                5426984.4114  1019547         
  22593 21255  5372956.2581   440                5426984.4114  1021651         
  22910 21449  5360374.1876   576                5426984.4114  1022311         
Elapsed time = 470.00 sec. (342129.94 ticks, tree = 10417.44 MB, solutions = 0)
Nodefile size = 8263.60 MB (4646.00 MB after compression)
  23237 21859  5360335.4920   575                5426984.4114  1031050         
  23560 22046  5383736.0244   537                5426984.4114  1032783         
  23879 22426  5360333.9633   576                5426984.4114  1034900         
  24119 22732  5378781.2447   415                5426984.4114  1036538         
  24393 22999  5360321.5653   574                5426984.4114  1039237         
  24617 23392  5398904.1723  1155                5426984.4114  1066359         
  24936 23397  5392844.8271  1514                5426984.4114  1063103         
  25291 23694  5372215.0641   428                5426984.4114  1069151         
  25565 24143  5372213.8210   421                5426984.4114  1080186         
  25833 24498  5378351.9222   405                5426984.4114  1091270         
Elapsed time = 527.85 sec. (380399.19 ticks, tree = 12081.63 MB, solutions = 0)
Nodefile size = 9987.11 MB (5635.13 MB after compression)
  26112 24647  5372183.3830   418                5426984.4114  1092716         
  26388 24796  5391904.6857   967                5426984.4114  1111331         
  26638 25128  5372042.5916   424                5426984.4114  1110020         
  26918 25490  5372036.4388   424                5426984.4114  1132170         
  27227 25682  5390109.8411   640                5426984.4114  1137477         
  27478 25965  5372001.7107   424                5426984.4114  1148303         
  27757 26212  5394104.4759  1459                5426984.4114  1171142         
  28054 26395  5378084.1732   395                5426984.4114  1163286         
  28399 26826  5378077.2330   392                5426984.4114  1179971         
  28693 26951  5371934.7413   413                5426984.4114  1182067
```

I have tried couple of hyperparameters like bbinterval, nodeselect, feasiblity, etc. but it keeps running for hours and not able to find and feasible or optimal solution.

Comment: "hyperparameters"? Just solver options. Nothing hyper about these. Anyways, some nodes being infeasible is normal. I would try an elastic formulation.

Comment: Following on from Erwin's comment, what happens if you try to relax (or simply not add) some constraints? Also the problem has very many variables (around 15x more than the number of constraints) and they are almost all integer variables which is unusual. Do all those variables really need to be defined as integers, or can you allow some (most?) to be continuous variables?